# How to change ID of cloned element in SVG when using <use>

Tags: svg, element

I am having SVG file where I want to display large amount of same elements so I am using  like in this example:

```html
<svg width="250mm" height="297mm" viewBox="0 0 250 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle id="1770" cx="63" cy="9.375" r="2" stroke="#9ACD32" opacity="0.4" onclick="alert('click!' + id)"/>
<use href="#1770" id="1771" x="10" y="0" />
</svg>
```

As you can see, on click event fires alert where id is returned, and the same id is returned for cloned element, regardless of id change in "use". Does SVG supports this kind of id overriding?

If not, then I will have very large SVG because all elements has to be written x times...

Comment: I would put the circle in a `<defs>` element and use it twice for the 2 circles. Now you can delete the click event for the circle and add clic events to the use elements

Comment: Yes! That is the right solution. Using `<defs>` as a container for elements allows definition of new element with new id, thus making it clicable unique. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So this is the right solution:

```html
<svg width="250mm" height="297mm" viewBox="0 0 250 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
 <circle id="circ" cx="63" cy="9.375" r="2" stroke="#9ACD32" opacity="0.4" />
</defs>
<use href="#circ" id="1771" x="20" y="0" onclick="alert('click!' + id)"/>
<use href="#circ" id="1772" x="10" y="0" onclick="alert('click!' + id)"/>
</svg>
```